# if-else depends on whether T is a complete type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, incomplete-type

How to check whether a certain type is a complete type in a certain `.cpp`?

```
template<class T>class Test{
    //some fields
    void(*functor)(T*) =[](T*){}; 
    //^ will be written by some .cpp that can access T as complete-type 
    T* t=nullptr;
    void fComplete(){    
        delete t;     //faster
        /** ^ some code that use complete type*/    
    }
    void fForward(){
        functor(t);   //slower
        /** ^ some code that forward declaration is enough*/   
    }
    void f(){  
        /*if(T is complete type){    
            fComplete();
        }else fForward();*/
    }
};
```

[**demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d804d1b977a0aab0)

It will be useful when I want to <s>prematurely</s> optimize a delete function in my custom smart pointer.

Can anyone confirm that it is impossible?
I am not asking for a workaround (but I don't mind) - this question is just my curiosity.

Comment: I had hope that this would work but sadly it doesn't... https://ideone.com/nEGsZu

Comment: You can make work things depending on whether a type is complete or not, but you template must ALWAYS evaluate to the same thing, or there will ODR violation.

Comment: If you evaluate with you type trait that a type is incomplete, then in all you translation units your trait must result in the same result.

Comment: @Curious sorry if it wasn't clear. It's a comment to the question. Attempting to branch at compile-time depending on if a type is complete or not is a bad idea, especially if that type might be complete in another translation unit.

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot  My gut also tells me (lightly) that it is a bad idea, but I can't find any specific reason.   If you don't mind, may you share some reasons please?

Answer (score 7):

This works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class Incomplete;
class Complete {};

template <typename IncompleteType, typename = std::enable_if_t<true>>
struct DetermineComplete {
    static constexpr const bool value = false;
};

template <typename IncompleteType>
struct DetermineComplete<
        IncompleteType,
        std::enable_if_t<sizeof(IncompleteType) == sizeof(IncompleteType)>> {
    static constexpr const bool value = true;
};

int main() {
    cout << DetermineComplete<Complete>::value << endl;
    cout << DetermineComplete<Incomplete>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** I like to use `std::enable_if_t` for the same effect as `void_t` until that is available instead of writing its implementation myself everywhere.

**Note** Do take a look at the other answer as well about ODR. They bring up a valid point that you should consider before using this.

Comment: Now evaluate that in two contexts, one where it is complete and one where not, and I suspect your program becomes ill formed, no diagnoatic required, due to ODR violations.  I believe this holds even cross compilation unit.  So "works" seems a bit if a stretch.

Comment: @Yakk note added

Answer (score 2):

There's a rule in C++ called ODR. The very basics of this rule (from my understanding)  is that something can have as many declarations as you want, but only one definition. It seems simple, but with templates and inline function, is quite easy to break it.

With templates, multiple definition is inevitable. Instantiation of the same template will happen in all translation unit that uses it. It seems against the one definition rule, but for inline and templated entities, the rule is extended. Here's a paragraph on cppreference:

> There can be more than one definition in a program, as long as each
>   definition appears in a different translation unit, of each of the
>   following: class type, enumeration type, inline function with external
>   linkage inline variable with external linkage (since C++17), class
>   template, non-static function template, static data member of a class
>   template, member function of a class template, partial template
>   specialization, as long as all of the following is true:
>
> - each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically, appears in the same header file)
> - name lookup from within each definition finds the same entities (after overload-resolution), except that constants with internal or
>     no linkage may refer to different objects as long as they are not
>     ODR-used and have the same values in every definition.
> - overloaded operators, including conversion, allocation, and    deallocation functions refer to the same function from each
>     definition (unless referring to one defined within the definition)
> - the language linkage is the same (e.g. the include file isn't inside    an `extern "C"` block)
> - the three rules above apply to every default argument used in each    definition
> - if the definition is for a class with an implicitly-declared    constructor, every translation unit where it is odr-used must call
>     the same constructor for the base and members
> - if the definition is for a template, then all these requirements    apply to both names at the point of definition and dependent names at
>     the point of instantiation
>
> If all these requirements are satisfied, the program behaves as if
>   there is only one definition in the entire program. Otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.

In short, if any function template expands to slightly different things in some translation units, you end up in the UB land. Trust me, debugging ODR violation is the worst, because your program might work for a long time, and suddenly crash when changing some compilation options, like optimisations.

In your particular case, you want to detect if a type is complete or not to change the definition of a function. Since in some places you might have a complete type **and** instantiate that function, you'll end up with multiple and different definition of that function.

Be careful with macros too. If some macro definition changes in only some translation and you use that macro in a template or inline function, you violate ODR, since the function won't consist of the exact same tokens.

---

Now, I acknowledge that other answers also are useful indeed. Detecting whether a type is complete is not entirely useless. I use it in my code.  I use it to provide nice diagnostics with `static_assert`, which even some implementations of the STL do (`unique_ptr` destructor in GCC's STL).

Comment: I do not think you need a function template: the detection idiom of `is_incomplete<T>` must be the *same8 in every translation unit.  This means the onky way for this to be legal is if it is incomplete everywhere or nowhere, which means the OP's design is flawed fundamentally.