# Prevent instantiation of template class with an incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, incomplete-type

I'm writing a library. Its layout looks something akin to this:

```
/////////
// A.h //
/////////

#include <vector>

class B;

class A
{
    std::vector<B> Bs;

public:
    ...
};

/////////
// B.h //
/////////

class B
{
    ...
}

///////////
// A.cpp //
///////////

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

// Implementation of A follows
...

///////////
// B.cpp //
///////////

#include "B.h"

// Implementation of B follows
...

/////////////
// MyLib.h //
/////////////

#include "A.h"
```

As you can see, the only type accessible from the outside is supposed to be `A`, that's why `B` is declared as an incomplete type in `A.h`. The library itself compiles fine, but when it comes to using it in a program, the compiler issues errors like: `invalid use of incomplete type B` when I try to create an object of type `A`. These errors point to the `vector` header, specifically, to the `std::vector`'s destructor, which apparently needs to know the size of the type it holds to deallocate the internal storage properly. What I think is happening is that the compiler is trying to instantiate `std::vector<B>::~vector` in my program, which can't succeed for aforementioned reasons. However, there are symbols for `std::vector<B>::~vector` in the library's binary, so I could do without instantiating it in the program. I'm looking for a way to tell that to the compiler. I've already tried changing `MyLib.h` to something like this:

```
/////////////
// MyLib.h //
/////////////

#include "A.h"
extern template class std::vector<B>;
```

This unfortunately doesn't work, because `extern` applies only to the code generation stage of the compilation, and the compiler still reports errors while parsing. I thought that maybe the compiler is trying to instantiate `std::vector<B>::~vector` because `A` has an implicit destructor, so I tried implementing a destructor manually like this:

```
/////////
// A.h //
/////////

#include <vector>

class B;

class A
{
    std::vector<B> Bs;
    ~A();

public:
    ...
};

///////////
// A.cpp //
///////////

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

A::~A() {}

// Further implementation of A follows
...
```

This doesn't help either, the compiler is still trying to instantiate `std::vector<B>::~vector`, even though it shouldn't ever be invoked outside the library code now. Is there a different way to achieve what I want or would it be best to choose a different method of information hiding for `B`?

Comment: You cannot use `std::vector` with an incomplete type, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Every constructor of `A` (including the implicit copy/move constructors) needs the destructor of `vector<B>`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try and prevent instantiations with undefined types explicitly, let the compiler do its job.  If you try and prevent instantiations with undefined types manually you might risk violating ODR, for more look here [if-else depends on whether T is a complete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340073/if-else-depends-on-whether-t-is-a-complete-type)

You can dump the values in the vector in `unique_ptr`s to add a layer of indirection.  For more information about how `unique_ptr` works with incomplete types look here [std::unique_ptr with an incomplete type won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile) For example

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#include "something.hpp"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {

    Something something;

    return 0;
}
```

### something.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Incomplete;
class Something {
public:
    Something();
    ~Something();
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Incomplete>> incompletes;
};
```

### something.cpp

```
#include "something.hpp"

class Incomplete {};

Something::Something() {}
Something::~Something() {}
```

---

Also consider reading this blog post http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm, it outlines an alternative to dynamic allocation if you are against that

Comment: I am aware that using something like `std::unique_ptr` would work in this case, it's just that it's a very cumbersome solution in my opinion. It introduces unnecessary memory fragmentation where there's really no good reason for it. I think I would rather expose `B` than change the layout of my class. I'd like to achieve both of course, but what I'm saying is that this solution doesn't really speak to me.

Comment: @PiotrOlszewski there is no solution to what you want in C++ currently unfortunately, you will need to define a pointer type one way or another,  you can choose to make a POD type that contains the `Incomplete` data and then manually construct it when you have the definition available but that also seems too cumbersome

Answer (score 2):

**ATTENTION, POSSIBLE DARK MAGIC:** *[I am not sure whether](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44664807/1116364) (or since when) one is allowed - by the standard - to define a member `std::vector<T>` with an incomplete type `T` if **none** of the vectors member functions (**including constructors and destructor**) is referenced from the current translation unit. I think C++17 allows this, though.*

One possibility that compiles since C++11 (though it could be illegal, see above) is the use of an `union` member to avoid calls to both the constructor(s) as well as to the destructor of the `std::vector` member:

```
struct Hidden;

struct Public {
    union Defer {
        std::vector<Hidden> v;
        Defer();
        // add copy/move constructor if needed
        ~Defer();
    } d;
};
```

Now, in your implementation file, you can (and must) actually call the constructor(s) and destructor of the vector:

```
struct Hidden { /* whatever */ };
Public::Defer::Defer() { new (&v) std::vector<Hidden>(); }
Public::Defer::~Defer() { v.~vector<Hidden>(); }
```

Of course, **using the member `d.v` in any way will need the definition of `Hidden`**. Thus you should limit such uses to the (non `inline`) member functions of `Public`, which you implement in file(s) that have access to the complete definition of `Hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is enough space for the vector, and all vectors in every implementation I know of take the same space regardless of what they store.

We can exploit this, while asserting we are right.

```
struct A {
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(std::vector<int>), alignof(std::vector<int>)> v;
  A();
  ~A();
};
```

in A.cpp

```
#include<b.h>
static_assert(sizeof(std::vector<B>)==sizeof(std::vector<int>), "size mismatch");
static_assert(alignof(std::vector<B>)==alignof(std::vector<int>), "align mismatch");

std::vector<B>& get_v(A& a){ return *(std::vector<B>*)&a.v; }
std::vector<B> const& get_v(A const& a){ return *(std::vector<B> const*)&a.v; }

A::A(){
  ::new ((void*)&v) std::vector<B>();
  try{
    // rest of ctor
  }catch(...){
    get_v(*this).~std::vector<B>();
    throw;
  }
}
A::~A(){
  get_v(*this).~std::vector<B>();
}
```

Also manually write copy/move ctor/assign.

We might be able to automate this, but it is tricky; we want the fact we are really a vector of B to only cause code to be created in A.cpp, nowhere else.